# General relation between size and maximal transmission distance of a transmitter

Tags: power, signal, transmitter, information

Suppose I want to build a transmitter to send detectable signals to receivers far away and still want the transmitter is be small. Is this in general possible?

Namely, how would the size of critical components of a transmitter (say, oscillator, antenna, etc.) affects its maximal power output and transmission range/distance?

Comment: You did not ask but there is a strong relationship between antenna size and transmission frequency. Higher frequency = smaller antenna. Also, there is a relationship between antenna size and antenna directionality or gain: higher gain requires larger size. Sensitive systems usually have a very large antenna on one side or the other. There is probably a relationship between transmit power and size also. It is difficult to get high transmit power in a very small size. So I guess the answer is, if your receive antenna can be large, your transmitter can be small.

Comment: Oh, and then there is the issue of interference from other radio sources and RF noise sources between the transmitter and receiver. In some cases that may thwart any effort to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, providing you have a sensitive enough receive system (big antenna, low noise amplifiers) and can tolerate very low data rates.

The Voyager 1 spacecraft has a 22.4 W transmitter and is at the outer fringes of our solar system.  Yet it is still sending data back to earth stations.

Here's another question in that same vein: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9824/how-much-rf-transmit-power-does-dsn-need-to-send-commands-to-voyager

Comment: Love the linked question! Voyager 1 isn't small (antenna is almost 4 meters in diameter) and the Goldstone system is "kind of big." I think the Seiko Message Watch (now defunct) would be better. It was actually a watch that received messages from FM sidebands in the local area. And it would run on a button battery for 2 yrs! That's a very tiny receiver carefully nursing power. Of course, the transmitter is huge. Something, either transmitter or receiver or both, is usually going to be big for long distance with current tech, as you indicate.